# Python Pandas GroupBy to calculate differences in months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A data frame below and I want to calculate the intervals of months under the names.

Lines so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

csvfile = StringIO(
"""Name Year - Month    Score
Mike    2022-11 31
Mike    2022-11 136
Lilly   2022-11 23
Lilly   2022-10 44
Kate    2023-01 1393
Kate    2022-10 2360
Kate    2022-08 1648
Kate    2022-06 543
Kate    2022-04 1935
Peter   2022-04 302
David   2023-01 1808
David   2022-12 194
David   2022-09 4077
David   2022-06 666
David   2022-03 3362""")
    
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

df['Year - Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year - Month'], format='%Y-%m')
    
df['Interval'] = (df.groupby(['Name'])['Year - Month'].transform(lambda x: x.diff())/ np.timedelta64(1, 'M'))

df['Interval'] = df['Interval'].replace(np.nan, 1).astype(int)
```

But the output seems something wrong (not calculating right).

Where has this gone wrong, and how can I correct it?

```
     Name Year - Month  Score  Interval
0    Mike   2022-11     31         1 <- shall be 0
1    Mike   2022-11    136         0
2   Lilly   2022-11     23         1
3   Lilly   2022-10     44         1 <- shall be 0
4    Kate   2023-01   1393         1 <- shall be 3
5    Kate   2022-10   2360         3 <- shall be 2
6    Kate   2022-08   1648         2
7    Kate   2022-06    543         2
8    Kate   2022-04   1935         2 <- shall be 0
9   Peter   2022-04    302         1 <- shall be 0
10  David   2023-01   1808         1 <- shall be 1
11  David   2022-12    194         1 <- shall be 3
12  David   2022-09   4077         2 <- shall be 3
13  David   2022-06    666         3
14  David   2022-03   3362         3 <- shall be 0
```

Comment: `df['Interval'] = df['Interval'].replace(np.nan, 1).astype(int)` -> shall be `.replace(np.nan, 0)`, also `.fillna(0)`.

Comment: Why shall the first row of `Kate` be `3`?

Comment: `.replace(np.nan, 1)` is one issue, but you need further explain why some diff are 2 and 3 like index 10 and 11.

Comment: @Quang Hoang, Ynjxsjmh thank you for the helps. the intervals are from the upper (row) month minus lower (row) month. and I've corrected the manual samples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to difference with next value instead of previous value. You can do so by setting -1 in `diff()`.

```
...

df['Interval'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Year - Month'].transform(lambda x: x.diff(-1)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
df['Interval'] = df['Interval'].fillna(0).round().astype(int)
```

Result:

```
     Name Year - Month  Score  Interval
0    Mike   2022-11-01     31         0
1    Mike   2022-11-01    136         0
2   Lilly   2022-11-01     23         1
3   Lilly   2022-10-01     44         0
4    Kate   2023-01-01   1393         3
5    Kate   2022-10-01   2360         2
6    Kate   2022-08-01   1648         2
7    Kate   2022-06-01    543         2
8    Kate   2022-04-01   1935         0
9   Peter   2022-04-01    302         0
10  David   2023-01-01   1808         1
11  David   2022-12-01    194         3
12  David   2022-09-01   4077         3
13  David   2022-06-01    666         3
14  David   2022-03-01   3362         0
```